# Android multiple URLConnections

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

My question is pretty simple. Its whether it is safe to have one instance of a urlconnection, open it and use multilpe requests on that instance (GETs and POSTs). I've been noticing some bad latency in my requests, and I'm thinking that this has a lot to do with it. As of now, each activity creates its own instance of my httpurlconnection class which opens up a new connection per request.

Comment: as per http, each request requires its own connection.

Comment: Even if its the same url I'm connecting to?

Comment: yes. if you can modify the server, you can use SPDY, which is supported by, for instance, okhttp client, which allows to use the same connection for several requests. You can also use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection but I don't know if HTTPURLConnection uses that

Comment: @njzk2 this is not true in all cases. Androids `HUC` tries to reuse connections under the hood (keepAlive). So if you do many requests in sequence, it should reuse the connection.

Answer (score 0):

https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/android-port.html

Check out samples at the link for "thread pool connection". Using a good, threaded client that u implement to produce async type exec stack, you may config the number of connections per domain.

Async + threadpooled connections will speed your network bottleneck